# Can RSA key be determined when encrypted text is displayed alongside the clear text?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I would like to encrypt some text and display part of the encrypted text alongside the clear text as a means to prove that I generated it.

For example, let's say I have the text **ABCDE** that I want to prove that I generated.  Using RSA encryption with a private key, I encrypt this text and display the last few characters of it:

**szqKTeKU=**

Now I want to display both these on a label.  It'll have ABCDE on it and underneath, the text szqKTeKU=.

Later on, if we want to verify that this label with ABCDE was indeed generated by me, we can go back through the encryption process again, extracting the last characters and looking for a match.  Since the key would be a secret, only certain people would be able to complete this verification (actually, in practice, a program I will write will do it).

**Now, my question is: does the fact that I display the clear text as well as part of the encrypted text defeat its security?**

Comment: A public key is usually assumed to be public, thus available to all. Therefore, if encrypting **ABCDE** always yields a string ending in **szqKTeKU=**, anyone knowing the former can find the later (and if it does not, as is the case for proper RSA encryption since it is randomized, there's no way to verify the later). This goes straight against your apparent goals. If you try to fix this by making the public key secret, then you are using RSA as a [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), and there are better constructions for that, e.g. HMAC.

Comment: Thank you @fgrieu.  I did intend that the 'public' key would actually be private in practice.  I will look into Message Authentication Codes.

Comment: On the other hand, if you can afford the cryptogram to be larger (e.g. a QR-code), then it can hold a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). This basically performs the task of a MAC, except no secret is required to perform the verification (which uses the public key, whereas computing the signature is with the private key). RSA can be used for signature, if the relatively large signature size is tolerable.

Comment: EdDSA can also be used for signatures, and has a smaller signature size. ECDSA is another choice, though it requires a good CSPRNG for every signature.